# subset data only if observations of 2 variables match with each other in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, subset

I have data like so:

```
a <- c("blue", "red", "green", "blue","cyan")
b <- c("red","red","green","blue", "orange")
df <- data.frame(a,b)
df

      a      b
1  blue    red
2   red    red
3 green  green
4  blue   blue
5  cyan orange
```

I am trying to subset the rows if blue and red match with each other and watch with themselves.

I am trying following code but there are still some other colors that are matching one of these colours when I see check them using table function.

```
 sub <- df[df$a %in% c("blue", "red" & df$b %in% c("blue","red"), ]
 table(sub$a, sub$b)
```

It is very tricky for me. How can I tell R to subset only if blue and red match with each other and watch with themselves?

Desired output is:

```
      a      b
1  blue    red
2   red    red
3  blue   blue
```

Ultimate goal of doing this is to create 2 by 2 contingency table by separating then from 5 by 5 contingency table. If there is another suggestion to do this, that would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

This is what I mean by I don't want. I just want to keep observations blue & red observations. I don't want any observation of green, orange, cyan.

```
            Blue        Red            Green        Orange   Cyan
  Blue       28          39              32            3        1  
  Red        47         244             184           56        3
  Green      0           0               0            0         0
  Orange     0           0               0            0         0
  Cyan       0           0               0            0         0
```

Comment: There is a missing `)` in your attempt. Try `df[df$a %in% c("blue", "red") & df$b %in% c("blue","red"), ]`. You'll get desired result.

Comment: ok, thank u.  I corrected and run. but result is still the same.

Comment: sorry that is my mistake when I create example output.

Comment: Can you update your example input? You might share `dput(head(df, 20))`

Comment: I am sorry I don't know what should I upload when I use this dput(), I got something like this "structure(list(sp.tree = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Juniperus thurifera", 
"Pinus pinea", "Quercus faginea", "Quercus ....". Should I upload it?

Comment: Yes! Include the entire output at the end of your question.

Comment: What is "red" and what is "blue" now given your new sample data?

Comment: don't need to assign them, please just choose first 2 species names like Juniperus thurifera & pinus pinea

Comment: Like so `out <- subset(df, sp.tree %in% c("Pinus pinea", "Quercus ilex") & sp.near %in% c("Pinus pinea", "Quercus ilex")); table(droplevels(out))` ?

Comment: Gald it worked. That's pretty much @s_t's answer. Please consider to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the `droplevels()` function, as:

```
# here the markus solution
twobytwo <- df[which(df$a %in% c("blue", "red") & df$b %in% c("blue","red")), ]
#here the droplevels, that removes the unused level
table(droplevels(twobytwo))

         b
a      blue red
  blue    1   1
  red     0   1
```

More infos [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/droplevels.html).

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```
output <- df[df$a %in% c('red','blue') & df$b %in% c('red','blue'),]
```

Comment: yes, this is what I tried but still there are some other colors that are matching with blue or red like (gree=blue or orange =blue). this is not what I want.  I want observations like blue=blue, red=red, or red=blue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to filter your `data.frame` using `grepl`:

```
require(tidyverse)

result <- df %>% 
  varhandle::unfactor() %>%
  filter(grepl(pattern = paste(c("red", "blue"), collapse="|"), a) |
         grepl(pattern = paste(c("red", "blue"), collapse="|"), b))

result
     a    b
1 blue  red
2  red  red
3 blue blue

table(result)
      b
a      blue red
  blue    1   1
  red     0   1
```

Comment: with my data, all the observations comes out except last 2 by 2 matrix (only they are 0)

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following. I used your sample data.

Comment: it is ok. Thank you for your response and affort!